# Network Services Account

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis

HI All,

I have a .NET application which connects to a Web Service. Application pool for the Web service works under Network Services account. Everything was working fine till yesterday and somehow it started giving error today. When I changed the application pool account from Network Services to an Admin level account, everything started working fine.

As far as I know, Network Services account has top level privilage on the local system.

My question is, can Network Services account lose its permissions? If yes, how to give those permissions back again?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The "Network Service" account *doesn't* have admin-level privileges by default; that's what the "Local System" account is for. "Network Service" was introduced, along with "Local Service", exactly for this reason: have service accounts *without* full administrative privileges on the system.